# What evaluation metric should I use to compare knowledge based approach with generative model?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, chatbot, precision-recall, recurrent-neural-network

My team and I are working on developing a chatbot for technical support and we have two models- Generative model using rnn algorithm and Knowledge based approach using NLP. I would like to know if I want to compare these two models, what evaluation metric should I use. For generative model, I can compare rnn, tf-idf and lstm algorithms using recall@k metric. Is there any industrial standard to compare rnn algorithm with knowledge based approach?

Comment: Well, that depends. What are you trying to optimize for? Is the chatbot supposed to find answers in the existing KB? Do you have a gold standard dataset or manual annotations to compare against?