# Performance metric for DNN chatbot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, nltk, chatbot

I want to evaluate the performance of [pretrained chatbot models](https://github.com/Conchylicultor/DeepQA#pretrained-model), which are based on the [Neural Conversational Model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.05869) by Vinyals and Le. I have researched error metrics such as BLEU or perplexity; however, I feel like these do not make sense here, as there is no "ground truth" to compare to. The chatbot is intended to do small talk, not translate text, do question answering or any of the like.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46518041/what-evaluation-metric-should-i-use-to-compare-knowledge-based-approach-with-gen), but sadly, it was not answered.

Comment: This question was probably not answered because there is no simple answer to that. How do you want to evaluate it? Do you want to compare it to another model? Do you want to assess how well the technical assistance is? What is the application area (domain)? Can you evaluate alongside annotated data (information loss)? Quite often, chatbots and recommender systems are compared against with crowdsourcing subjective opinions, but this is not your intention, right?

Comment: Since the model is meant to do small talk, it is hard to specify an application domain. I am generally interested in different approaches to evaluation that already exist in related work. What do you mean by "crowdsourcing subjective opinions"?

Comment: I was working on a recommender system for a company, and the improvement in comparison to the former support chatbot was assessed by using Amazon Mturk. Crowdworkers were asked which support helped them better in technical issues, in order to find out whether the installation of the new system was worth the effort.  But such an approach may be harder for small talk, and by the way, getting significant results in opinions may be really costly, especially if you need a representative amount of workers. Even if you get good quality assessment, opinions are no objective metrics, so its subjective.

Comment: @Merlin Could you please explain more on the data you are training on also the model architecture details.

Comment: I used the model architecture as defined by Vinyals and Le and trained on the Cornell Movie-Dialogs Corpus. My question was answered by @CLpragmatics, because they highlighted that asking for a numerical performance metric is not really appropriate here.